# Java: Loop string length time complexity

Tags: java, string, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I am learning Big O notation and am wondering what the time complexity for this for loop would be.

```
public int loop(String text)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {   
        result += text.charAt(i);   
    }

    return result;

}
```

I'm not sure if the time complexity would be O(n) or O(1). I know if the loop was going to n I would assume a time complexity of O(n) but I'm not sure if text.length() would mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let n be the number of characters in your string.
Your loop obviously iterates n times (since text.length() == n), with each iteration doing constant work (addition).

Your loop should be O(n)

EDIT: The other answers are wrong. You are not returning a string, nor appending to a StringBuilder. You are adding the int value of each ASCII character, and returning the total.

Comment: Are you just assuming `text.length()` is O(1) or is this documented somewhere? The C function `strlen` is O(n), for example.

Comment: In C, strings are null terminated char arrays. You can have a char array of length 200, but if the first null byte is at index 100 you'll have a length of 100. This means you actually have to loop over the string and count each byte until you hit null.

IIRC, in Java strings are immutable and hold exactly N characters in the Object's private member field. Then you can get it in O(1) because getting the size of the array is O(1) (it's kept as metadata), and that corresponds exactly to the string length in Java.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite a safe assumption, but I was just trying to make sure. The documentation for `String.length` doesn't say anything about its complexity: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length-- (but I guess it would have, if it was somehow O(n) :-)).

Comment: I usually assume that if it's easy to keep it as metadata, then it's probably O(1). E.g. it'd be silly to recompute a Hashmap or List's size every time you query for it rather than just do O(1) work to keep track of it. If you're writing performance sensitive code then you'll want to revisit that assumption and make sure by digging into the documentation or source code (:

Answer (score 0):

It's O(n). However, a simple change can make it `O(1)` here. Change the method body to `return text;`. `String` is immutable; creating a copy character by character is pointless.